# How do I separate login interface with header footer and without it

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xhtml, authentication

I want to know how to get different login interface for my web **`without`** change to the **`URL`** name. Example

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://domain.com/login/">Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

If user click on the **`Login`** I want to make it display on Ajax popup. Just show the login & password form. I'm using ColorBox. Example [Outside HTML (Ajax)](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html)

If user type `http://domain.com/login/` that page will include header, footer and etc.

Let me know what to put in my `login.php` to make it to be different.

Comment: you have to make your own popup html and you can use one of jquerys method to show and hide , other you can use lot of available jquery plugins

Comment: some good link http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-using-jquery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to put any changes to your `http://domain.com/login` (potentially). You just have to attach the colorBox plugin to the link. It handles the popup and the `e.preventDefault()` call so people won't get the popup *and* the page. It's usually best to give the links an Id or class (like I have below).

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="loginlink" href="http://domain.com/login/">Login</a></li>
</ul>

$('a#loginlink').colorbox({href:"/yourLogin.html"});
```

Since you're using the Outside HTML example, you can do the above (replacing the filename with your actual HTML).

However, since it's not an incredibly huge piece of code to display a login form, you can include it in your page (but hidden) and pass this to the ColorBox plugin using the Inline Html example:

```
$('.loginlink').colorbox({
    inline: true,
    width: "50%",
    href: "#loginBox"
});
```

An example of the inline HTML working: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/MHhNX/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use URL parameters: http://domain.com/login/?ajax=1 for ajax, and http://domain.com/login/ for full page.

HTML:

```
<a href="http://domain.com/login/" onclick="ajaxLogin();return false;">Login</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function ajaxLogin () {
      $.ajax({url: 'http://domain.com/login/?ajax=1', ... });
   }
</script>
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET['ajax']) && $_GET['ajax'] == 1) {
   // ajax form
} else {
   // full page
}
```

Comment: The query string is well included as a part of the URL. And the user could also click on the link which links to the AJAX version.

Comment: @ryanli, I don't change href. User with disabled javascript redirects to non-ajax version

Answer (score 0):

blur ,

You have to change your html a bit assuming that you are using jquery

give a class name for this

```
<a href="http://domain.com/login/" class="loginpopup">Login</a

$('.loginpopup').click(function() {
   // construct your html here and show as popup , or you can use existing dialog boxes
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing would need to change in login.php. You'd need to add an onclick handler to your link however.

Take a look at jquery to help you out with this: http://api.jquery.com/click/